# Mongo C#, set all array elements in nested property

Tags: c#, mongodb

How do I set a whole array in a subproperty of a Mongo document?
This is my current document model, a house with rooms and each with furnitures.

```
public enum Furnitures{
   Table,
   Chair
}

public class House{

   public string Id {get; set;}

   public Room[] Rooms {get; set;}
}

public class Room {

    public string Id {get; set;}

    public Furniture[] Furnitures {get; set;}
}
```

This is my update method, but it is not working:

```
void InteriorDesign( IMongoCollection<House> collection, string houseId, string roomId, Furniture[] newfurnitures)

{
    filterBuilder = Builders<House>().Filter;
    var filter = filterBuilder.Eq( x => x.Id, houseId) &
      filterBuilder.ElemMatch( house => house.Rooms, room => room.Id == roomId);

    updateBuilder = Builders<House>.Update;
    var update= 
    // HERE I EXPECT the NEW array replace the old one
    updateBuilder.Set( house => house.Rooms[-1].Funitures, newfurnitures);

    collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter,update);
}
```

How do I replace the content of one array with another brand new array?

Comment: Your code looks ok. Which MongoDB driver version are you using ?

Comment: version 2.7.0.. FindOneAndUpdate should return the updated document is that right?

Comment: forgot to tell Funitures is a enum (for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct but `FindOneAndUpdate` returns the document **before** modification ([docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)). To change that you need to specify additional parameter:

```
FindOneAndUpdateOptions<House> options = new FindOneAndUpdateOptions<House>();
options.ReturnDocument = ReturnDocument.After;

var result = collection.FindOneAndUpdate(filter, update, options);
```